# Latitude e6540 fails to install wifi network drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, dell-latitude

After reinstalling Windows 7 to my dell Latitude e6540 I downloaded a number of drivers using the machine its service tag on the dell website to ensure the right drivers were provided. 
When I attempt to install the wifi drivers (various versions) the process exists with: "This software package cannot be installed on your system"

Reinstalling the chipset drivers and then attempting to install the network drivers failed to remedy the issue.

The install log of the driver reports ERROR_INSTALL_PLATFORM_UNSUPPORTED:

> ﻿[07/22/17 22:34:40]   Update Package Execution Started
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] Original command line: "C:\Users{user}\Downloads\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19.EXE" 
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] DUP Framework EXE Version: 3.4.4.35
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] DUP Release: 48WF6A19
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] Initializing framework...
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] Data in smbios table is (hex)value = 9 , Chasis type (hex)value = 9 , System type is : Client 
>   [07/22/17 22:34:40] logo.png
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] User Command: attended
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] DUP Capabilities Value: 35651583 (0x21FFFFF)
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] DUP Vendor Software Version: 18.33.0.2
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Local System/Model Compatible with this Package? Yes
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Local System OS Version: 6.1.1.0
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] OS Compatible with this Package? Yes
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Local System OS Language: NL
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Language Compatible with this Package? Unknown
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Extraction-miniunz path: C:\PROGRA~3\B1A363~1\dell\drivers\NETWOR~1.2_A\miniunz.exe
>   [07/22/17 22:34:44] Extraction-arguments:  -x C:\Users{user}\DOWNLO~1\NETWOR~2.EXE -o -d C:\PROGRA~3\B1A363~1\dell\drivers\NETWOR~1.2_A
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Extraction-GetExitCode: 0
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Identified Behavior : attended
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Temporary payload log file name: C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19\DUP424D.tmp
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Translated Command Line : mup.exe /v"/c mup" /l:"C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19\DUP424D.tmp"
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Path : C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19
>   [07/22/17 22:34:48] Identified Behavior : attended
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] Append Vendor Software Log: C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19\DUP424D.tmp
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] 
>   --- Start of Vendor Software Log ---
>
> [07/22/17 22:34:53]    ASCII payload log file detected.
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] ****************************************
>   MUP started: Sat Jul 22 22:34:48 2017
>
> Command Line: C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19\mup.exe /v/c mup /l:C:\ProgramData\b1a363a5-9d74-4cf5-a74b-aea50b20023e\dell\drivers\Network_Driver_48WF6_WN32_18.33.0.2_A19\DUP424D.tmp
>
> ---
>
> Execute: setup.exe   /c mup
>   Error: setup.exe exited with return code: 104
>   MUP finished: Sat Jul 22 22:34:53 2017
>
> Exiting with Return Code: 104
>
> [07/22/17 22:34:53]
>   --- End of Vendor Software Log ---
>
> [07/22/17 22:34:53]    Vendor Software Return Code: 104
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] logo.png
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] Name of Exit Code: ERROR_INSTALL_PLATFORM_UNSUPPORTED
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] Exit Code set to: 5 (0x5)
>   [07/22/17 22:34:53] Result: FAILURE

Comment: Sometimes the installer can fail, despite it has the correct driver. Try extracting the content of the installer to get the driver out (some installer can be extracted using 7-zip, or the installer itself can extract it for you) - and then from Device Manager, select the wifi device that has the exclamation point, and choose "update driver" and point it to the folder where the extracted driver is.

Comment: Is there another driver shown in Device Manager that needs to be uninstalled?

Comment: Device Manager does not list a wifi device, a network controller is listed as without drivers.
Extracting the drivers executable and installing the wifi driver using "Wifi.msi" fails too though it reports the driver as successfully installed.

Comment: Running Dell command update does not install the wifi driver. The Intel PrOset wireless troubleshooter does detect the wifi driver is missing but the troubleshoot button does nothing.